# WebRTC; Sharing screen of peer 1 to peer 2 connections are made, track is send but no video

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I'm trying to do the following with WebRTC, connect two peers to each other, for now on the same machine (different tabs)

- Peer 1 starts it's connection and shares his screen (the track is added on the connection)
- Peer 2 accepts the offer and posts the answer to the signal server
- Peer 2 receives the track and is added to the video element
- Peer 1 accepts the answer and remote is set

Still the video element doesn't render any video
Things I've tried;

- I use a STUN and TURN server from Twillio (when tested with trickle ice over TCP, I get state done)
- When using the stream on peer 1, the video of screen is shown
- When using a normal video in peer 2 the normal video is shown
- In chrome://webrtc-internals/ I can't see any frames send or received
- In firefox I do see the error `WebRTC: ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details` but I can't figure out what the problem is. Besides that the ICE trickle failed `rickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.`

I hope someone has suggestions to look for more info or try things. I'm quite stumped why I can't make it work

Comment: Can you share the code you used?

Comment: Can't really find the problem from just a description

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I've cached the ice candidates because I've read somewhere this was a good approach.. but really it isnt
So that why they never got added and exchanged.